# Doesn't choose records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii, yii2

```
author   id  |  name            
         1       Mike
         2       Dive
         3       Stiv
```

---

```
book     id  |  title
         1       ABC
         2       War
```

---

```
book_author  id_book | id_author
             1         1      
             1         2
             2         3
```

---

app/models/Book.php

```
public function getAuthors()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Authors::className(), ['id' => 'id_author'])->viaTable('book_author',['id_book' => 'id']);
}
```

In view:

```
    foreach (Books::findAll([1, 2]) as $book)
    {
        echo sprintf('%s | %s',
            $book->title,implode(', ',
                $book->getAuthors()));
    }
```

Always returned **implode(): Invalid arguments passed** in **$book->getAuthors()));**

**getAuthors()** - doesn't choose author, why?

Need:

ABC    |    Mike, Dive
  War    |    Stiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$book->getAuthors()` get object arrays. You should get simple array. Try this code:

```
foreach (Books::findAll([1, 2]) as $book)
    {
        $authors = ArrayHelper::toArray($book->getAuthors()->all(), [
         'app\models\Authors' => [
           'name', 'id'
         ]
        ]);
        echo sprintf('%s | %s',
            $book->title,implode(', ',
                ArrayHelper::map($authors, 'id', 'name')));
    }
```